# Why is my Button Not Working in Electron JS?

Tags: javascript

So I'm working on a small desktop app for myself, and for some reason I can't get the buttons to do anything. I am using skeleton CSS. I was able to get buttons working using this method previously, but for some reason it's no longer working.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="skeleton.css" type="text/css">
<head>
   
    <h3>Which Term is Correct?</h3>

</head>
<body>

    <div class="form">
        <label>First Search Term</label>
        <input type="text" name="name">

        <label>Second Search Term</label>
        <input type="text" name="email">

       <input id="subButton" type=submit value="Submit">
       <input id="histButton" type=submit value="History">
       <input id="exitButton" type=submit value="Terminate">

    </div>
    <script>
        const remote = require('electron').remote;
                document.querySelector('#exitButton').addEventListener('click', () => {
                    let w = remote.getCurrentWindow()
                    w.close();
                })
    </script>  
</body>

<style type="text/css">
.form {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 210px;
        text-align:center
    }

    .form label{
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: right;
        margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto
    }

    .form input{
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: left;
        margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto
    }

    
    
</style>

</html>
```

Comment: I found the solution! 

So I mentioned in my original post that I got this code to work before, but could no longer do it. I've tried like a dozen things over the last hour and finally went into the package.json file of my old project and compare it to the package.json of my new project to see if I was missing some imports. When I compared the package.json files of the two projects I found something interesting. 

The old project was on Electron 9 whereas the new one is Electron 10. In version 10 the remote module is disabled by default. Simply adding  "enableRemoteModule: true" fixes it!

Answer (score 0):

You typed

```
<input id="subButton" type=submit value="Submit">
```

You should be typing

```
<input id="subButton" type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Notice the quotation marks around `submit`. See if this solves it.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not fix it.